# Messenger class accessibility

Tags: mvvm, toolkit, light, mediator, messenger

I'm using MVVM Light's Messenger class.
I'm wondering if this class's should be used only by ViewModels, or if it can be used also by other classes.
If it's the latter, then who also can use it? IoC Conainer? Services? Views?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most often you'll use it for communication between ViewModels, but it's also used for opening new windows in the codebehind, or for communicating with the ViewModelLocator class. It's not really WPF-specific, just a messaging service.